# pyspark: IOError: [Errno 20] Not a directory

Tags: pyspark, amazon-emr

I am running a pyspark job on AWS-EMR and I got the following error:

```
IOError: [Errno 20] Not a directory: '/mnt/yarn/usercache/hadoop/filecache/12/my_common-9.0-py2.7.egg/my_common/data_tools/myData.yaml'
```

Does anyone know what I might have missed? Thanks!

Comment: share more info: command, spark job or input/output arguments.

Comment: Did you find the solution? I am facing the same issue

Answer (score 1):

I've run into this recently when I switched my Python Spark application from Client deploy mode to Cluster deploy mode.

My workaround is to locate the ZIP file (the artifact that I fed to `spark-submit` using `--py-files`):

```
  CURRENT_FILE_PATH = os.path.dirname(__file__)
  print("[DEBUG] CURRENT_FILE_PATH=" + CURRENT_FILE_PATH)
```

It comes out something like this:

```
/mnt2/yarn/usercache/task/appcache/application_1638998214637_0019/container_1638998214637_0019_02_000001/something.zip
```

then I can use something like:

```
  import zipfile
  archive = zipfile.ZipFile(CURRENT_FILE_PATH, 'r')
  json_bytes = archive.read('myfile.json')
  json_string = json.loads(json_bytes)
```

Note: I first tried using pkg_resources but couldn't read in the
resulting JSON due to TypeError from json.loads():

```
import pkg_resources
json_data = pkg_resources.resource_stream(__name__, 'myfile.json')
```

See also [PySpark: how to resolve path of a resource file present inside the dependency zip file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53281314/pyspark-how-to-resolve-path-of-a-resource-file-present-inside-the-dependency-zi)

Answer (score 0):

As the error states `my_common-9.0-py2.7.egg` is not a directory.

Are you missing space in your path?

`/mnt/yarn/usercache/hadoop/filecache/12/my_common-9.0-py2.7.egg /my_common/data_tools/myData.yaml`