# PySpark: how to resolve path of a resource file present inside the dependency zip file

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

I have a `mapPartitions` on an RDD and within each partition, a resource file has to be opened. This module that contains the method invoked by `mapPartitions` and the resource file is passed on to each executor using the `--py-files` argument as a zip file.

To make it clear:

```
rdd = rdd.mapPartitions(work_doing_method)

def work_doing_method(rows):
    for row in rows:
        resource_file_path = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), "resource.json")
        with open(resource_file_path) as f:
            resource = json.loads(f.read())
            ...
```

When I do this after passing the zip file which includes all of this using the `--py-file` parameter to the spark-submit command,

I get `IOError: [Errno 20] Not a directory:/full/path/to/the/file/within/zip/file`

I do not understand how Spark uses the zip file to read the dependencies. The `os.path.dirname` utility returns the full path including the zip file, for eg. `/spark/dir/my_dependency_file.zip/path/to/the/resource/file`. I believe this should be the problem. I tried many combinations to resolve the path of the file. Any help is appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We get the path to a resource file within an egg/zip file (inside the executor working dir) when we look for the absolute path. I ended up using the zipfile module in Python and actually open it like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49782111/access-a-file-from-a-python-egg/49782154#49782154).

Comment: Yeah, this works, but I'd love to have a solution that works in both client and cluster deploy modes.

Answer (score 1):

I think when you add a file to a Spark job, it will be copied to the working directory of each executor. I've used the [SparkFiles API](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.2.0/api/python/pyspark.html?highlight=file#pyspark.SparkFiles) to get absolute paths to files on the executors.

You can also use the `--archives` flag to pass in arbitrary data archives such as zipfiles. [What's the difference between --archives, --files, py-files in pyspark job arguments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38066318/whats-the-difference-between-archives-files-py-files-in-pyspark-job-argum)

Comment: The spark files API is a good solution but it will break the abstraction of the dependency module that we have (the absolute path has to be passed on to the dependency module from the spark job client). I am currently exploring packaging as an egg file or a wheel file (which could bunde data files as well?), so far no luck though.